# Cual es la mejor y más eficiente manera de leer un JSON en Android

Tags: java, android-studio, json, app

Logro leer este un link por JSON que me funciona bien pero cuando la consulta es de mas de 100 registros, el aplicativo se demora mucho y el teléfono hace mucho esfuerzo.

este es el método que demora mucho y quisiera mejorarlo:

```
public String call(String url) {
        Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "Iniciar leyendo");
        int BUFFER_SIZE = 2000;
        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "antes del OpenHttpConnection");
            in = OpenHttpConnection(url);
            Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "despues del OpenHttpConnection");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE: ERROR AL CREAR CONEXION  OpenHttpConnection ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "antes del InputStreamReader");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
        Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "antes del InputStreamReader");
        int charRead;
        String str = "";
        char[] inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
        try {
            Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "antes del while");
            while ((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer)) > 0) {
                Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "dentro del while");
                Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "Leyendo el inputBuffer ");
                String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer, 0, charRead);
                Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "readString =  " + readString);
                str += readString;
                Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "CADENA =  " + str);
                inputBuffer = new char[BUFFER_SIZE];
            }
            in.close();
            Log.d("Lectura de CADENA ", "despues del while");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ERROR: ", e.getMessage() + ": MENSAJE: ERROR AL LLAMAR LA URL ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: Este código solo lee un `String` (sea JSON o no); normalmente será el proceso (parseo) del JSON (el montar las estructuras de datos) lo que lleve más tiempo. ¿Estás seguro de que es este el código que va lento?

Comment: Hasta ahi en el codigo no hay procesamiento de ningun json solo una lectura de String a partir de una URL. Te aconsejaria no crear arreglos, puedes utilizar un `BufferedReader` y un `StringBuilder` en lugar de manejar el arreglo tu y concatenar Strings respectivamente.

Comment: ¿Por qué mejor no usas [`Volley`](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html) para obtener el JSON. Luego la lectura del JSON es muy fácil, incluso lo puedes mapear a un adaptador personalizado. [Aquí tienes un tutorial completo](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2015/02/android-volley-peticiones-http/) escrito en español.

Comment: Utilicé BufferedReader y StringBuilder. Quedó de 2 a 5 segundos más lento.